# Auto detect environment in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I recently started developing a application in Laravel. I develop on 2 machines (home workstation and laptop) and will run the "production" app on another machines.

There are several settings that differ on these machines (most notable DB_USERNAME/DB_PASSWORD

What would be the best way to automatically have laravel detect the environment it's running on (for instance by hostname or ip)?

I found some tutorials like https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-environment-detection-and-environment-variables and http://developers.ph/laravel-framework/laravel-5/how-to-setup-multiple-environment-for-laravel-5-developers-way/ but they seem to rely on manually setting the environment somewhere instead of detecting it.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. Using environment variables is likely the best way to do this. You can set the variables in your Apache/Nginx vhost.

Comment: You should place environment related settings in .env file. This file should not be shared among hosts

Comment: You have to set the environment value somewhere( in this case, it is .env file) because unless you tell the system, how will it know which environment it is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the root of your Laravel installation there will be an `.env` file containing your configuration - set these up but do not include them in your source control. Contents of the file below.

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=mandrill
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: Ok, I was thinking a bit too much along the lines of just copying everything over, including the .env file. I now see that it's best to copy everything expect the env file.